# Transform from 2-level MultiIndex to 3-level MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have something with the following data structure:

```
               foo  year
par  chi                
10.0 900  0.024096  1983
     901  0.200000  1983
     902  0.300000  1983
     900  0.027473  1984
     901  0.023256  1984
     902  0.400000  1984
     900  0.018182  1985
```

That is, for each parent-child-year combination I have some observation of  `foo`. Now, for each parent, I would like to compute the Covariance between each `chi` and each other `chi` (in this data set, 900 and 901), over time (that is, how do entries of `foo` in `chi_1` and `chi_2` covary over time, for a given `par`?).

I suppose the "easiest" way is to introduce `chi` a second time as a third-level index into the dataset, but I all I got was:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([par, chi, chi])
```

where `par`, `chi` are the unique values of the index. However, I couldn't find a way of reindexing my data with that in a way that is useful to the exercise. How would I proceed with this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the covariance between entries of `foo` within-`year` across-`chi` or within-`chi` across-`year`?

Comment: @splinter Within-year across chi

Comment: @FooBar To be clear for each `par` you want to generate the combination of `chi`, then generate the covariation.

Comment: @shanmuga There is more than two `chi` (I changed the example to emphasize that). For each pair of 2 `chi`, I want to look at the time series of their `foo` and compute the covariation. Did that clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Solution plan:

- start with a dataframe with four columns (reset index if necessary)
- for each `par` group apply a function that calculates child covariances
- in the function unstack group so that its index is `year` and values of `foo` for each child are in separate columns
- compute covariances and melt the result so that you get a row per `chi` and `chi_other` combination.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chi': [900, 901, 902, 900, 901, 902, 900],
 'foo': [0.024096, 0.2, 0.3, 0.027473, 0.023256, 0.4, 0.018182],
 'par': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
 'year': [1983, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1985]})

def child_covariances(group):
    x = group.set_index(['year','chi'])['foo'].unstack()
    x = pd.melt(x.cov().reset_index(), id_vars=['chi'], 
                var_name='chi_other', value_name='foo_cov')\
          .set_index(['chi','chi_other'])\
          .query('chi <= chi_other').sort_index()
    return x

res = df.groupby('par').apply(child_covariances)
#                     foo_cov
# par chi chi_other          
# 10  900 900        0.000022
#         901       -0.000298
#         902        0.000169
#     901 901        0.015619
#         902       -0.008837
#     902 902        0.005000
```

Comment: `group.set_index(['year','chi'])['foo'].unstack()` can be replace by `df.pivot(index='year', columns='chi', values='foo')`